# Se ha producido un error al realizar la inyección de recurso en el bean administrado chartView

Tags: java, primefaces

```
    package org.primefaces.examples;

    import Conexion.conexion;
    import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
    import java.io.Serializable;
    import static java.lang.System.out;
    import java.sql.ResultSet;
    import java.sql.SQLException;
    import java.util.logging.Level;
    import java.util.logging.Logger;
    import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
    import org.primefaces.model.chart.Axis;

    import org.primefaces.model.chart.AxisType;
    import org.primefaces.model.chart.BubbleChartModel;
    import org.primefaces.model.chart.BubbleChartSeries;

   @ManagedBean
   public class ChartView implements Serializable {

   private BubbleChartModel bubbleModel1;
   private BubbleChartModel bubbleModel2;

  @PostConstruct
   public void init() {
   createBubbleModels();
}

public BubbleChartModel getBubbleModel1() {
    return bubbleModel1;
}

public BubbleChartModel getBubbleModel2() {
    return bubbleModel2;
}

private void createBubbleModels(){
    bubbleModel1 = initBubbleModel();
    bubbleModel1.setTitle("Bubble Chart");
    bubbleModel1.getAxis(AxisType.X).setLabel("Price");
    Axis yAxis = bubbleModel1.getAxis(AxisType.Y);
    yAxis.setMin(0);
    yAxis.setMax(250);
    yAxis.setLabel("Labels");

    bubbleModel2 = initBubbleModel();
    bubbleModel2.setTitle("Custom Options");
    bubbleModel2.setShadow(false);
    bubbleModel2.setBubbleGradients(true);
    bubbleModel2.setBubbleAlpha(0.8);
    bubbleModel2.getAxis(AxisType.X).setTickAngle(-50);
    yAxis = bubbleModel2.getAxis(AxisType.Y);
    yAxis.setMin(0);
    yAxis.setMax(250);
    yAxis.setTickAngle(50);
}

private BubbleChartModel initBubbleModel(){
    BubbleChartModel model = new BubbleChartModel();

    conexion c=new conexion();
    ResultSet re=c.consulta("select count(*), nombre from usuario where Nombre like 'a%' or nombre like 'b%' group by nombre;");
    try {
        while (re.next()) {


        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ChartView.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }



    return model;
}
```

com.sun.faces.mgbean.ManagedBeanCreationException: Se ha producido un error al realizar la inyección de recurso en el bean administrado chartView
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.invokePostConstruct(BeanBuilder.java:227)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.build(BeanBuilder.java:103)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.createAndPush(BeanManager.java:409)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.create(BeanManager.java:269)
    at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.resolveBean(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:257)
    at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.getValue(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:117)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:116)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getBase(AstValue.java:151)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:200)
    at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:226)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
    at org.primefaces.component.chart.Chart.getModel(Chart.java:105)
    at org.primefaces.component.chart.renderer.BubbleRenderer.encodeData(BubbleRenderer.java:33)
    at org.primefaces.component.chart.renderer.BasePlotRenderer.render(BasePlotRenderer.java:29)
    at org.primefaces.component.chart.ChartRenderer.encodeScript(ChartRenderer.java:98)
    at org.primefaces.component.chart.ChartRenderer.encodeEnd(ChartRenderer.java:67)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:920)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1863)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:458)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:134)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:659)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: com.sun.faces.spi.InjectionProviderException: com.sun.enterprise.container.common.spi.util.InjectionException: Exception attempting invoke lifecycle  method public void org.primefaces.examples.ChartView.init()
    at org.glassfish.faces.integration.GlassFishInjectionProvider.invokePostConstruct(GlassFishInjectionProvider.java:231)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.invokePostConstruct(BeanBuilder.java:221)
    ... 56 more
Caused by: com.sun.enterprise.container.common.spi.util.InjectionException: Exception attempting invoke lifecycle  method public void org.primefaces.examples.ChartView.init()
    at org.glassfish.faces.integration.GlassFishInjectionProvider.invokeLifecycleMethod(GlassFishInjectionProvider.java:393)
    at org.glassfish.faces.integration.GlassFishInjectionProvider.invokePostConstruct(GlassFishInjectionProvider.java:306)
    at org.glassfish.faces.integration.GlassFishInjectionProvider.invokePostConstruct(GlassFishInjectionProvider.java:229)
    ... 57 more
Caused by: java.security.PrivilegedActionException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.glassfish.faces.integration.GlassFishInjectionProvider.invokeLifecycleMethod(GlassFishInjectionProvider.java:376)
    ... 59 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.glassfish.faces.integration.GlassFishInjectionProvider$2.run(GlassFishInjectionProvider.java:382)
    ... 61 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Conexion/conexion
    at org.primefaces.examples.ChartView.initBubbleModel(ChartView.java:61)
    at org.primefaces.examples.ChartView.createBubbleModels(ChartView.java:38)
    at org.primefaces.examples.ChartView.init(ChartView.java:26)
    ... 66 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Conexion.conexion
    at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1783)
    at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1633)
    ... 69 more

Comment: Incluye los metodos Set, para ambas variables de instancia BubbleChartModel.

Answer (score 0):

Comprueba que tu aplicación incluye la clase `Conexion` en el classpath

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Conexion.conexion
```

Comment: si ya la tengo, y esta importada a la clase de java
 import Conexion.conexion;

Comment: Una cosa es que te compile y otra que tu war/ear la incluya en ejecución. Entiendo que es una clase de un jar externo. Revisa la carpeta lib del war/ear generado a ver si está.

Comment: sl war/ se encuenta en la lib,  que es MySQL JDBC Driver

Comment: Si la clase Conexion no es parte de tu proyecto, tiene que estar en un jar en WEB-INF/lib del war generado, ¿es así?